# .htaccess interpreted differently by local and prod server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

It works on my local server and when I access `http://localhost/prefix/test` my php script recieves:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] => string '/prefix/test/'
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'] // not set
```

And this is works great. Unfortunately when I access `http://domain.hostinger.pl/prefix/test` i recieve

```
No input file specified.
```

I changed my `.htaccess` to this: (I added `?`)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [L]
```

And I no longer recieve `No input field specified` but on my local server my php script recieves:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] => string '/prefix/test/'
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'] => string '/test/'
```

And my prod script recieves:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] => string '/prefix/'  // totally wrong
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'] => string '/'
```

Can anybody tell me what to do so that my prod script can recieve correct parameters? (Like this one from local script with original `.htaccess`)? Or tell me why this happens?

Comment: Check [this](http://htaccesscheatsheet.com/htaccess.php?tip=serve-all-requests-with-one-php-file). I believe you need a different rewriterule.

Comment: @forrestmid Unfortunately this didn't work for me :/

Comment: Have you checked any other `$_SERVER` variables to see if the path you're looking for is somewhere else? I believe that's worth a look. You could just `print_r($_SERVER)`, but if you do make sure you're webserver is secure because it will dump environment variables.

Comment: @forrestmid Framework I use only uses `REDIRECT_URL` and `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` for setting routes.

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`.

Comment: @forrestmid This didn't work either (i had same effect as you're first link). But I changed my framework core filesso it finds routes another way. So everything works now:) Thank you.